# Is there any reason to not caulk/foam between the garage door jamb and rough opening?

Tags: concrete, insulation, doors, garage, caulking

There is a gap between the rough edge and the garage door jamb.  From some research, it seems like it's common practice to caulk/spray-foam this area to prevent drafts/etc. However, before doing so, I was wondering if there is any reason to *not* do this?  It just seems bizarre to me why such a thing was done and wanted to make sure it wasn't an oversight from the builders.

Some possibly relevant details:

- Our house is in the Pacific Northwest (snows maybe once a year, otherwise usually high 30s at worst in the winter, very rainy).
- The garage is concrete and the garage doesn't feel insulated at all (so maybe builders decided not to fill out the gap because the garage isn't insulated anyways?).
- The garage contains the hot water tank as well and all the tank overflow is supposed to drain out of the garage (wondering if that might be a possible reason for the gap as well).

[image: gap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because it would look like hell and make a mess.  Normally you never see where people use spray foam.

Perhaps a roll of foam insulation would be better.

[image]